# What would be the simplified form of this expression?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

I'm working on a Homework problem involving Convergence of Random variables and I've arrived at an expression which looks like follows:

$$ M_{X_n}(ju)= \prod_{k=1}^{n}0.5\frac{1-e^{\frac{ju}{2^{k-1}}}}{1-e^\frac{ju}{2^k}}$$

,where $M_X(ju)$ denotes the characteristic function of a random variable $X$. It'd be great to have an hint to proceed as I've not seen(or remember) a product like this before and I'd love to show my work here but this is just a single step of a big homework problem and I'm just stuck at this part. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have too many thoughts about this particular step. (I know some work has to be shown, but really I don't seem to find a way through this step and that's the reason why I'm posting this; Thank You !!)

Edit: I made an error in the initial equation and I've rectified it. $0.5$ should have been inside the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $e^{ju/2^{k}} = t$, then $t^2 = e^{ju/2^{k-1}}$

Comment: I actually had arrived at the expression I've posted from what you've given. The work was as follows: The initial expression was: $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(0.5+0.5e^{\frac{ju}{2^k}})$$ and I used $0.5(1+a)=0.5\frac{1-a^2}{1-a}$ where $a=e^\frac{ju}{2^k}$. And the convergence under question is $$X_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{Z_k}{2^k}$$ where $Z_k$ are IID Bernoulli random variables with $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Think of the $Z_k$ as binary digits...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update, I got the equation simplified (embarrassingly it was a simple thing) and $X_n \rightarrow U[0,1]$. Thank you for the help !